# How do I call the method on the inherited object?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a project with the Pi and Python. I have coded more in Java and C#, and I am having trouble calling the start method of the parent class when calling from the inherited class.

Here is my main file:

```
import picamera
import time
import ConfigParser
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from multiprocessing import Process
from datatrack import DataTracker
from datatrack import CameraTracker
camera = picamera.PiCamera()

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('./config.ini')

tracker = CameraTracker(config)
tracker.start()
```

Then in the datatrack file I have:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import time

class DataTracker():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.buttonPressLast = False;
        self.dataTracking = False;
        self.totalTime = 0.0
        self.timeBetweenData = float(config.get("Data", "TimeBetween")) 

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            self.buttonPress = False
            if(GPIO.input(24) == 0):
                self.buttonPress = True

            if(self.buttonPress == True and self.buttonPressLast == False):
                self.buttonPressLast = True
                self.dataTracking = not self.dataTracking
                if(self.dataTracking):
                    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
                else :
                    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif (self.buttonPress == False and self.buttonPressLast == True):
                self.buttonPressLast = False

            if(self.dataTracking and self.totalTime >= self.timeBetweenData):
                self.capture_data()
                self.totalTime = 0.0
            self.totalTime += .1
            time.sleep(.1)
    def setup(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

    def capture_data(self):
        print ("Capture data")

    def start(self):
        self.setup()
        GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.loop()

def CameraTracker (DataTracker):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(CameraTracker, self).__init__(config)
        self.camera = False

    def capture_data(self):
        print("Take pictures here")
```

I am fine when the code in the main file is calling the DataTracker constructor. However, when I switch things over to CameraTracker as above i get the following output in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "camera_capture.py", line 17, in <module>
    tracker.start()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your question here: raspberrypi.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: After look at this for an hour.. I have realized that I tried to define the class using the def keyword instead of class..

Comment: I've done this before in my own code. It's seriously one of the most difficult typo bugs I've ever had to figure out, since (if the class is constructed with one argument) it fails silently.

Comment: Yes! It is very hard to catch

Comment: @GauravDave Please don't promote [cross-posting questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).